# How to bind command into a context menu that is inside TreeView on it's items?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, command

I want to be able to execute a command on an item inside the TreeView by clicking the command in the context menu. And to be more specific only if the item is of a certain type (the xxTreeViewItem is an interface with 2 subtypes).

```
   <Grid Name="Root" commonExtensions:EnterKeyUpdateExtension.IsEnabled="True">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Center on" Command="{Binding Path=CenterOnCommand}" Margin="5,10,5,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <TreeView Grid.Row="0" Name="xxTreeView" DataContext="{Binding Path=xxViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Center On" Command="{Binding CenterOnCommand}"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" DataType="{x:Type localViewItems:xxTreeViewItem}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

The Command in the button on the top works, but it does not work below in the context menu. I tried several bindings and finding of the ancestor but none of it works. Is there XAML only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` does not belong to the visual tree, so it does not inherit your TreeView's DataContext. So you need to pass it to your ContextMenu by using the PlacementTarget property:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=DataContext}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Center On" Command="{Binding CenterOnCommand}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I hope it can help you

Comment: It's still not working, the command CenterOnCommand is in xxEditorViewModel. xxViewModel used in the TreeView is a Property of the xxEditorViewModel. Solved it by setting the Setter's AncestorType to UserControl (the top). Thanks!